# Filtering CustomFilter values on YouTrack

Tags: issue-tracking, youtrack

I'm currently customizing YouTrack to adapt some processes of a company.

It's possible to filter, by Workflow or rest API, custom fields bundle values based on some criteria? (ex.: by value `name`, `description` or `colorIndex`).

The idea here is to basically chain project/issue fields in a way that the second field hide values that are not of the first field concern.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this feature is not released yet, but can be tracked on the issue [JT-12511](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-12511).